# Can namespaces enable multiple domains?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces, google-cloud-datastore

My gae app serves multiple domains by `if..else..` conditions rather than namespaces.
I see someone else solved it with namespaces

> "I have a single app with multiple namespaces defined.
>
> I'd like to set up multiple domains
>
> a.com b.com c.com
>
> and have the app detect the domain and write the domain's data into
>   its respective namespace."

I don't know how to do it with namespaces and I want a better way to add a domain to the app for settings like content and languages. For example sending an email via a form then I use just a condition instead of namespace.

```
class FileUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    adminemail = 'admin@domain1.com' if gethost() is 'domain1' else 'admin@domain2.com'
    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=admin_email, subject=self.request.POST.get('subject'))
    message.body = ...
    message.to='info@domain...
    message.send()
    self.redirect('/customer_service.htm')
```

I use same workaround for queries, localization and in some cases even which template to render to while I should be able to make all domains able to be based on same templates and differ only by content so that my app doesn't hard-code the domains and other settings that should be easy to add and change.

Are namespaces a great idea in this case? The way a managed the problem with different domains so far is a variable for the entity which domains it came from

```
if util.get_host().find('my-dot-com') > 0:
    url = 'www.my-dot-com.com'
```

I have a function that defines what I mean but it may confuse www.domain.com with domain.com or have problems with subdomains

```
def get_host():
  return os.environ.get("HTTP_HOST", os.environ["SERVER_NAME"])
```

I'd be glad to know any idea if you have, or if I'm mistaken and shouldn't use namespaces in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, namespaces are ideally suited to what you're doing. Simply store configuration data like admin emails in a per-domain configuration record, and store all the records for a given domain in a namespace named after that domain.

Comment: And if you need per-user info within a domain, use a namespace of "domain/user". Switching namespaces multiple times within a handler is fine.

Comment: @Dave That will work, but it's a rare site that completely siloes data per user (something like a password safe, perhaps).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answers and comments. I'd like to see some code also where my current implementation is very basic i.e. a varible `entity.url` that comes from `os.environ["SERVER_NAME"]` or HTTP_HOST that indicates a namespace. The entity also has the variable `entity.user` to indicate ownership and origin. I can create records for the domains and store them to make my code more like a whitelabel product and less hard-coded.

Comment: @Niklas Namespaces and how to set them per-request are documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/). If there's something in particular you're confused about how to implement, by all means ask away.

Comment: @Nick From the link I could find and learn from the example `guestbook_namespaces`. Thanks for the great help.